# Write dot-qmail recieved in to a file

Tags: email

I can sent qmail-received emails with `.qmail` to an other programm. This looks like this:

```
|/path/to/my/script
```

Easy! But now I need for debugging purposes just the content in a text file or similar? I tried

```
|/path/to/a/file
```

But this does not work, obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [manual](http://www.qmail.org/man/man5/dot-qmail.html), the classical single file with mail messages is called a *mbox*:

> An mbox line begins with a slash or dot, and does not end with a slash:

```
 /home/djb/Mailbox.sos
```

`qmail-local` takes the entire line as a filename.  It appends the mail message to that file, using flock-style file locking if possible.  qmail-local stores the mail message in mbox format, as described in mbox(5).

The alternative is of course to write each mail message to an unique file a.k.a. the  Maildir.

> A maildir line begins with a slash or dot, and ends with a slash:

```
 /home/djb/Maildir/
```